# Mysql search not searching with the whole string

Tags: php, mysql

My mysql search doesn't search with the whole string. my query

```
 $query_details= "SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE sn= '$phone' OR sentto= 
'$phone' OR batch= '$phone' ";
$details= $offices->query($query_details) or die(mysqli_error($xxxx));
$row_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($details);
```

when I search with something like '19Pa5vP9MyGoYoaB23kRNsHGjaRvYUHD' it rather brings our result for row with sn = '19'.

Please I need it to search with the whole string not just part of it.

Thanks.

Comment: i dont see how what you describe is possible, are you sure that's the right code?

Comment: does it return _only one_ row with sn=19? Or many rows including that one with sn=19?

Comment: is the field `sn` defined as int by any chance? (though I'd expect mysql to throw an error then)

Comment: it returns only 1 row.... more like it extracts the 19 from the string and uses it to search thereby returning the row that has 19 as sn

Comment: sounds like somewhere above there's an unintended cast to int happening with `$phone`. -> `echo $query_details` before you send the query to check what you've got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is defined as `INT`, then MySQL will try to convert the comparison string to an integer too. Since it starts with a number, MySQL will extract all the leading digits from the string (in this case 19), convert that to an `INT` and then do the comparison. Hence you get rows with `sn = 19` returned. For example:

```
SELECT 19 = '19c5bx'
```

Output

```
1 -- true
```

To get around this, `CAST` any integer columns as `CHAR` before comparison e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(19 AS CHAR) = '19c5bx'
```

Output

```
0 -- false
```

This will still work fine if you want to compare to an integer instead of a string e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(19 AS CHAR) = 19
```

Output

```
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf68248300aa5f1c04e0bdb03e44b372)

So something like this should work (cast the other columns as `CHAR` too if they are also `INT` in your table):

```
$query_details= "SELECT * 
                 FROM Purchases 
                 WHERE CAST(sn AS CHAR) = '$phone' 
                    OR sentto = '$phone' 
                    OR batch= '$phone' ";
```